# nbsp and css animation browser rendering issue

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
    background-color:#DFE1E1;
    font-family:sans-serif;
     margin-left:10%;
    }

a:nth-child(n+1) { 
  color: black;
  display:inline-block;
  border:5px solid rebeccapurple;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(0.25turn, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1, #f69d3c);
  animation: animate 5s ease-in 1 forwards;
}

a:nth-child(1) { 
  border:5px solid yellow;
  }

a:nth-child(2n+2) { 
  border:5px solid blue;
  }

a:nth-child(2n+3) { 
  border:5px solid magenta;
  }
  
@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    width: 0px;
  }
  100%{
    width:290px;
  }
}
```

```html
<a>A for Apple</a>
<a>B&nbsp;for&nbsp;Blue</a>
```

Please observe the css animation between the **A for Apple** and **B for Blue** text elements, so initially the animation is not smooth(bumpy I should say) for the text content **A for Apple** but eventually they smoothen on a single line but in the **B for Blue** the css animation is very smooth right from the initial to final stages (if I introduce a nbsp html like:   `<a>B&nbsp;for&nbsp;Blue</a>`) I actually dont want to use nbsp tags to avoid too much duplicacy in my html code, so please suggest alternative

Comment: I tested in both chrome and Firefox, and honestly, I find the "bumpiness" barely noticeable, and in my opinion it impacts both A and B equally.  My guess is that the ease-in, combined with a starting width of 0 and a linear background gradient, is just giving the appearance of a jerky animation, and I bet that if you play around with these 3 things, the impression of bumpiness will be gone.  If you don't agree, perhaps providing a more obvious example, or at least mentioning what browser you're observing the problem in, would be a good next step.

Comment: Microsoft Edge
Version 111.0.1661.44 (Official build) (64-bit) 
on WIN 10 . Ray's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75806153/21245853) worked by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the line-wrapping? You could avoid it by adding [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to keep it all on one line.

The example below removes the `nbsp`s and adds `white-space: nowrap` to the CSS.

```css
body {
    background-color:#DFE1E1;
    font-family:sans-serif;
     margin-left:10%;
    }

a:nth-child(n+1) { 
  color: black;
  display:inline-block;
  border:5px solid rebeccapurple;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(0.25turn, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1, #f69d3c);
  animation: animate 5s ease-in 1 forwards;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a:nth-child(1) { 
  border:5px solid yellow;
  }

a:nth-child(2n+2) { 
  border:5px solid blue;
  }

a:nth-child(2n+3) { 
  border:5px solid magenta;
  }
  
@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    width: 0px;
  }
  100%{
    width:290px;
  }
}
```

```html
<a>A for Apple</a>
<a>B for Blue</a>
```

Comment: perfect and accepted but why does the  line-wrapping/bumpiness /jerkiness phenomenon appear in browsers if you can add the concept ?

Comment: great insight ,   also working good would be the [white-space: pre;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Text wraps by default because most of the time you want it to stay within the bounds of its container.